# Passing a string in a method that takes a method as its parameter

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a method in a class called SqlInteraction:

```
public static string sqlQueryReturnString(Func<SqlConnection, string> sqlMethod)
{
    string result = "";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
    try
    {
        //open SQL connection
        conn.Open();
        result = sqlMethod(conn);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here is another method in a different class that uses it:

```
private string getPKofUserLoggedIn(SqlConnection conn, string PointPerson)
{
    int result = 0;
    SqlCommand getPKofUserLoggedIn = new SqlCommand("SELECT [PK_User] FROM [User] WHERE [LoginName] = @userIdParam", conn);
    //create and assign parameters
    getPKofUserLoggedIn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userIdParam", PointPerson);
    //execute command and retrieve primary key from the above insert and assign to variable
    result = (int)getPKofUserLoggedIn.ExecuteScalar();
    return result.ToString();
}
```

I am having trouble passing the string in the second method. If I remove 'string PointPerson' this call works:

```
SqlInteraction.sqlQueryReturnString(getPKofUserLoggedIn);
```

How do I pass the string as well?

Comment: I don't want to change sqlQueryReturnString because it's used many places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Func<SqlConnection, string>` reads as 'a function that takes a `SqlConnection` parameter and returns a `string`' - which, if you remove PointPerson then you have.

If you want to add a parameter from an outer method, you can do the following:

```
var myParam = "some string";
SqlInteraction.sqlQueryReturnString(conn => getPKofUserLoggedIn(conn, myParam));
```

Answer (score 1):

The last generic type parameter for `Func` is the return. The ones before that are the method parameters. You have to change your first method signature to:

```
public static string sqlQueryReturnString(Func<SqlConnection, string, string> sqlMethod)
```

This will allow it to accept a method with a return type of `string` and `SqlConnection` and `string` parameters.

If you don't want to/can't change the method signature of `sqlQueryReturnString`, then you can close over an outer variable:

```
string parameter = "myParameter";
sqlQueryReturString(conn => getPKofUserLoggedIn(conn, parameter));
```